# Start and Stop functionality of StopWatch is not coordinated iOS

Tags: ios, nstimer

I am creating a stopwatch and the start and stop functionality is not coordinated. When the timer stops, it doesn't start where it left of.

The code looks like this:

```
self.endDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:12.0f*60.0f];

-(void)startPressed:(id)sender{
    if(!_running){
        _running = TRUE;
        [sender setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        if (_stopTimer == nil) {
            _stopTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/10.0
                                                         target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(changeTimer:)
                                                       userInfo:nil
                                                        repeats:YES];
        }
    }else{
        _running = FALSE;
        [sender setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_stopTimer invalidate];
        _stopTimer = nil;
    }

}

- (void)changeTimer:(NSTimer*)timer {
    _timeInterval = [self.endDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    self.timerControl1.minutesOrSeconds = ((NSInteger)_timeInterval)%60;
    self.timerControl2.minutesOrSeconds = (NSInteger)(_timeInterval/60.0f);
    self.timerControl3.minutesOrSeconds = ((NSInteger)_timeInterval)%60;
}
```

I know it is because of timeIntervalSinceNow. But, how to change this? Need some guidance on this.

The problem:

When you stop the stopwatch and start it again after 3s for example, it shld still start back from the same timing. but both my code, the start and stop timing are different, they are starting from a different timing. Need help to solve this.

Comment: when are you setting endDate?

Comment: when loading the view.

Comment: any help? still not able to do it.

Comment: self.endDate IS strong right? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use the endDate in changeTimer but use the endDate only to init the timer

```
#import "RimsViewController.h"

@interface RimsViewController ()
@property(weak) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property(strong) NSDate *endDate;
@end

@implementation RimsViewController {
    BOOL _running;
    NSTimeInterval _timeInterval;
    NSTimer *_stopTimer;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.endDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10*60];
    _timeInterval = [self.endDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
}

-(IBAction)startPressed:(id)sender{
    if(!_running){
        _running = TRUE;
        [sender setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        if (_stopTimer == nil) {
            _stopTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(changeTimer:)
                                                        userInfo:nil
                                                         repeats:YES];
        }
    }else{
        _running = FALSE;
        [sender setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_stopTimer invalidate];
        _stopTimer = nil;
    }

}

- (void)changeTimer:(NSTimer*)timer {
    _timeInterval -= 1;// [self.endDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

    NSUInteger secs = _timeInterval;
    int h = (NSUInteger)secs/3600;
    secs-=h*3600;
    int m = (NSUInteger)secs/60;
    secs-=m*60;
    int s = secs;

    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d / %d / %d", h, m, s];
}

@end
```

Comment: u not getting it. When u stop the stopwatch and start it again after 3s for example, it shld still start from the same timing. but both my code and yours are starting from a different timing.

Comment: you are right I don't get it and im done trying too :) rephrase the question to make sense

Comment: Apologies my bad. I will rephrase it. thanks anyway.

Comment: @lakesh do you mean that the watch  keeps running in the background? then why do you use     `_timeInterval = [self.endDate timeIntervalSinceNow]` ... if so never use the date ;) I added that as an alternative too

Comment: yes. that's right. the watch is running at the background. _timeInterval = [self.endDate timeIntervalSinceNow] --> where do u add this? not getting u.

Comment: I edited the answer to only set the _timeInterval in viewDidLoad. then im just subtracting 1 (second) each time changeTimer is called

Comment: thanks a lot. that got it for me.appreciate your time and help.

Comment: shld be -0.1 instead of -1.

Comment: for milliseconds - yes